# VSCode Rust add semicolon on save

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rustfmt

I am using the Rust extension on vscode and NOT rust-analyzer. However, when I am saving a file, vscode is using rustfmt to format my file but it doesn't automatically insert semicolons. I have a trivial function like this

```
fn call_me() {
  let x = 5
  println!(x)
}
```

It doesn't add the necessary semicolons. How do I make it add semicolons? Are my installations somehow messed up?

Also, I have tried rust-analyzer and it doesn't add semicolons either.

Comment: Why would you want semicolon insertion? Rust semicolons change program behavior so inserting them could break stuff?

Comment: You're right. But shouldn't the editor scream at me with red squiggly lines complaining about possible errors? Vim coc-rust-analyzer screams at me but vscode doesn't. Only when I am trying to compile the file, it shows me the possible error.

Comment: Why aren't you using rust-analyzer? It is 1000x better.

Comment: rust-analyzer is also not showing errors until I compile. vim coc-rust-analyzer is working flawlessly though. Any idea why vscode rust isn't showing me errors?

Comment: "semicolons change program behavior" This is only true in certain situations, in the given example it would be safe to insert a semicolon on line 2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unlike JavaScript, semicolons are not *syntactically optional* in Rust. Thus, leaving them out is a **syntax error**, not just a matter of style, and `rustfmt` (the standard Rust code formatting tool) doesn't ever attempt to fix any syntax errors, no matter how “obvious” they might be — if it reads a file with errors it will not make any formatting changes.

(I don't know if there's a way to get rust-analyzer, vim, or VS Code to auto-insert semicolons as a matter of *editing* rather than formatting.)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not what you're looking for but there are language-agnostic options to reduce the friction of semicolon insertion.

For instance the vs code extension [colonize](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vmsynkov.colonize) adds the shortcut `alt+enter` which appends a semicolon and newline, no matter where in the line the cursor is.